# Confusion about varargs parameters

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I am very confused about this code:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

public class ComingThru  {
    static String s = "-";

    static void sifter(A[]... a2) { 
      s+="1"; 
    }

    static void sifter(B[]... b1) { 
      s+="2"; 
    }

    static void sifter(Object o) { 
      s+="4"; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A[] aa = new A[2];
        B[] ba = new B[2];
        sifter(aa,ba);
        System.out.println(s);
    }   
}
```

It is giving output as `-1`, but there should be a compile error as no matched function is found.

Comment: Why would you think that? Both `A` and `B` are assignable to `A`.

Comment: Btw, did you know that `method(MyType... mt)` is exactly the same as `method(MyType[] mt)`? Thus, `sifter(A[]... a2)` is the same as `sifter(A[][] a2)`.

Comment: @Cedric: Not exactly, the varargs version allows for no argument.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach: it's not *exactly* the same since using varargs will allow multiple (or none) parameters while the array will only allow one parameter in the form of an array. But they both translate to an array behind the scenes after the call, yes.

Comment: Oops, yes. It translates to it, i.e. all args are put into an array for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not give compilation error. since there is a perfect method signature matching the call since B is also A. That's is what is called inheritance. If you check the code again,

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

the above code makes it to compile and execute.

```
static void sifter(A[]... a2) { 
      s+="1"; 
    }
```

The above method can be *invoked by passing variable length of arrays of type A or its subtype (i.e. child class of A i.e. B)*

Answer (score 1):

The matching method is `static void sifter(A[]... a2)` since B extends A. 
That's why you don't get compilation error.

If you look deeper (i.e. compile/decompile), you will see that in the compiled bytecode you have the following.

```
    static void sifter(A a[][]) {...}

    static void sifter(B b[][]) {...}

    static void sifter(Object o) {...}

    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            A aa[] = new A[2];
            B ba[] = new B[2];
            sifter(new A[][] {
                aa, ba
            });
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Then it's clearer why it works OK, and why it calls the method it calls.

Answer (score 1):

[Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming. It states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e., objects of type S may be substituted for objects of type T.

So you can pass B as A to the  method where A is expecting and the match found.

```
 static void sifter(A[]... a2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A matched method is found

```
static void sifter(A[]... a2) { s+="1"; }
```

This method will be called since A is higher in hierarchy and it can catch B's reference in it.

That's why the output is `"-1"`

Answer (score 0):

Since B extends A it will match with this function

```
 `static void sifter(A[]... a2) { s+="1"; }` //means any number of arrays of type A can be accepted and B is of type A.
```

If you remove this you will get compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

That may help you to understand if you rename your class like this.

```
class Fruit {}
class Apple extends Fruit {}
```

Since an Apple is a Fruit, it's perfectly valid to call the method that requires arrays of Fruits (`static void sifter(Fruit[]... a2)`)